# Message Group expiring 2 times

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a spring flow where i am aggregating message. I am using time out to expire the group.

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="inputChannel" expire-groups-upon-completion="true" expire-groups-upon-timeout="true" discard-channel="timeoutChannel"  group-timeout="10000" correlation-strategy-expression="headers['id']" output-channel="release"/>
```

in  **timeoutChannel** i am sending email when any group is timeout. While seting email it fails( not able to connect to server that is fine) and send to error channel where i am logging the error.

I am not able figure out why its expiring message 2 times with same log message?

**Error Log**

```
2021-05-27 17:53:46,213 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler:528 - Cancel 'forceComplete' scheduling for MessageGroup [ SimpleMessageGroup{groupId=d02b06cb-1c59-2d87-a3d6-080de89799e4, 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,215 INFO  [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler:632 - Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[d02b06cb-1c59-2d87-a3d6-080de89799e4] 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,215 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler:643 - Discarding messages of partially complete group with key [d02b06cb-1c59-2d87-a3d6-080de89799e4] to: aggregatorTimeoutChannel 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,215 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:413 - preSend on channel 'aggregatorTimeoutChannel', 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,216 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:413 - preSend on channel 'aggregatorTimeoutAlert',
2021-05-27 17:53:46,218 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#0.handler received message: GenericMessage [
2021-05-27 17:53:46,219 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler:115 - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@18afd6e2] (timeOutAlertMailChain$child#1) received message:
2021-05-27 17:53:46,220 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#2.handler received message:
2021-05-27 17:53:46,221 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#3.handler received message: 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,222 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#4.handler received message: 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,222 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#5.handler received message: 
2021-05-27 17:53:46,225 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.mail.MailSendingMessageHandler:115 - timeOutAlertMailChain$child#6.handler received message: GenericM
2021-05-27 17:53:48,238 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:413 - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [timeOutAlertMailChain$child#6.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    2021-05-27 17:53:48,240 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageHandler:115 - org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageHandler#0 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [timeOutAlertMailChain$child#6.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"/><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)"/></head><body lang="EN-GB" link="blue" vlink="purple"><div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US" style="mso-fareast-language: EN-IE">
2021-05-27 17:53:48,240 ERROR [task-scheduler-1] com.examplet.ErrorHandler:26 - ERROR!!! 
error occurred in message handler [timeOutAlertMailChain$child#6.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
2021-05-27 17:53:48,241 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:432 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [timeOutAlertMailChain$child#6.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
```

Comment: Would you mind to share those logs with us? How does it work if you don't throw an exception?

Comment: Added error log, same log i can see one more time

Comment: Probably you use a default global `errorChannel` and also add to it your own logger.... Anyway: the problem feels like not about an aggregator, but more about your mail channel adapter and error handling for it.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I think this is happening because of message group expired and send to discard channel and when late arriving message comes it has same Seq Size so again it timed out and send to discard channel. In this case it send email 2 times for same message. I was looking into option  `<int:expire-advice-chain>` so that it will send only one email for one group wen there is any timeout. But not sure how to use this? can't find any examples.

Comment: Well, then it is definitely not the same logs. Just because the message is new. So, yeah, it is also discarded. You can consider to use a `<filter>` before sending to mail channel adapter.

Comment: how i can use `<filter>`?

Comment: See Idempotent Receiver: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver. Pay attention to its `MetadataStoreSelector`, which you can use in the filter's `ref`. The `MetadataStore` will keep track of groups already processed, so messages discarded from the aggregator later won't pass your filter to the mail channel adapter.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I was thinking to use `<int:expire-advice-chain>` with `send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"` so that when any time out happen it will release the group and send the email only once. But i am not able to figure out how to use this advice chain, is that something will work?

Comment: Not sure why would you need that one over there and how it can help you to filter out later messages... Yes, you need to rethink your solution around an aggregator and see if you really can rely on the regular group release, not only that discard part when timeout.

Comment: I am thinking to release the timed out group to reply/output channel and use `<int:expire-advice-chain>` to send email I am not going to filter any message here. As per documents it says `It allows the configuration of any Advice for the forceComplete operation.
It is initiated from a group-timeout(-expression) or by a MessageGroupStoreReaper and is not applied to the normal add, release, and discard operations.`

Comment: That sounds like a good direction. Let me add some answer for you on the matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to think about regular output emitting when expiration timeout happens. As you notices the `send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"` does the trick on the matter.

You probably need to think do not make `expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"`, but rather `false`. This way the expired group is not going to be removed from the store and all the late messages are going to be discarded since group is marked as `complete`.

I don't think there is a point for you to look into that `<int:expire-advice-chain>` since only one message per group is going to be emitted to the `outputChannel` according that our `send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"`.

See more docs about an aggregator and what does it do: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

**UPDATE**

If you wish to use an `<int:expire-advice-chain>`, you need to implement a `MethodInterceptor` like this:

```
public class ExpiredGroupNotificationMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public Object invoke(@NotNull MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        MessageGroup expiredGroup = (MessageGroup) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        Collection<Message<?>> partiallyReleasedMessages = expiredGroup.getMessages();
        // Do some notification here
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

}
```

And add it as a `<bean>` for that chain:

```
<expire-advice-chain>
    <beans:bean class="ExpiredGroupNotificationMethodInterceptor"/>
</expire-advice-chain>
```

As a nested configuration for your `<aggregator>` tag.

Comment: I agree but my requirement to send some kind of notification when its timed out. So thinking to add `<int:expire-advice-chain>` when it force complete.

Comment: Yeah, sure! It's also possible. See a `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`. you expect a `MessageGroup` as an argument to deal with and don't forget to call `invocation.proceed()`!

Comment: Not sure how to do this, can you please elaborate a bit on this? will be great if you can share some sample code? Thanks for you help again

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.